# syslog-ng issue in tagging to server

Tags: syslog-ng

I installed syslog-ng by using "yum install syslog-ng" in both local machine and server end. 
I am using an open source version of syslog-ng.

My need is to pass the log file name from client to server end . I explicitly set the .SDATA.file at 18372.4.name field on my
client side, as the name of the file is available in the $FILE_NAME macro. But ".SDATA.file at 18372.4.name" is empty
in server side. When I am using some static file name the log beings to work.

Below is my code I dont know where i am going wrong If you need more information I can provide you can anyone help me.

```
MY CLIENT END SYSLOG-NG CODE:
source s_application_logs { 
    file( 
        "/var/log/test.log"
        flags(no-parse)
    );
};

destination d_access_system {
    syslog( 
          "52.38.34.160"
          transport("tcp")
          port(6514)
    );
};

rewrite r_set_filename {
   set(
       "$FILE_NAME",
       value(".SDATA.file at 18372.4.name")
      );
};

rewrite r_rename_filename {
   subst(
         "/var/log/",
         "",
         value(".SDATA.file at 18372.4.name")
         type("string")
         flags("prefix")
        );
};

log {
    source(s_application_logs);
    rewrite(r_set_filename);
    rewrite(r_rename_filename);
    destination(d_access_system);
};



MY SERVER END SYSLOG-NG CODE:
source s_server_end {
              syslog(
                     port(6514)
                     max_connections(1000)
                     keep_hostname(yes)
                    );
};

destination d_log_files {
    file(
        "/var/log/test/${.SDATA.file at 18372.4.name}"
        create_dirs(yes)
    );
};

log {source(s_server_end);destination(d_log_files);};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the $FILE_NAME macro is currently available only in the commercial version of syslog-ng. For a possible workaround, see this blogpost: [Forwarding filenames with syslog-ng](https://czanik.blogs.balabit.com/2015/03/using-rfc5424-syslog-to-forward-file-names/)